# Foundation 5 Sticky Div

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, sticky

I am using **Zurb Foundation 5** and I am trying to achieve the following:

I have a `row` which contains a search box located somewhere in middle of the page. I want to **stick** the `<div>` which contains the search box **on top** once user scrolls down to it. Is there a built in class in foundation 5 to do it, and if not, what is an alternative way to do it? Note that I need it to be responsive such that I don't have to specify the distance from top to the div (scroll distance).

Comment: Check this link - http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sticky.html This might be helpful.

Comment: That Foundation 6. I am using foundation 5. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Magellan to do this in Foundation 5.

You can insert the following code within your page:

```
<div data-magellan-expedition="fixed">
  <div class="row" data-magellan-arrival="search">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <a name="search"></a>
      <div class="row collapse" data-magellan-destination="search">
        <div class="small-10 columns">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search the database">
        </div>
        <div class="small-2 columns">
          <button class="button postfix expand">Go</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've created this [example in CodePen](http://codepen.io/asonnenshine/pen/ZOmvGA)